# Pymongo $unset not working as expected

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to remove fields from this mongodb document but pymongo `$unset` is not working as expected.  What am I missing?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b7468c00f5f35010e8d37f9"),
"study_id" : 1,
"isActive" : true,
"credentials" : {
    "access_token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9",
    "expires_in" : 28800,
    "refresh_token" : "8e2d14c04207736cbb3afd9c83ba84fe73c51",
    "user_id" : "22MDW2",
    "scope" : [ 
        "a", 
        "b", 
        "c", 
        "d"
    ],
    "token_type" : "Bearer",
    "expires_at" : 1534544517.06537
}
```

}

I've tried various solutions and syntax from other stack overflow answers to no avail.

This works in the mongo shell:

`db.getCollection('users').update({'study_id': 1}, {$unset: {'credentials.user_id': 1}})`

But this doesn't work with pymongo:

`db['users'].update({'study_id': 1},{'$unset': {'credentials.user_id': 1}}))`

python 3.6

mongodb 4.0.1

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet - how would you tackle this with pymongo?

Comment: The `user_id` subfield should be removed from 'credentials' field in documents matching the filter. Your pymongo query looks alright to me. Do you get an exception running the query? You may want to look at your configuration to see if you have [RBAC](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/) configured.

Comment: yes just adding to what @OluwafemiSule said, do check if you are connecting to the primary server and not the secondary.Better if you could share the exception.
I have run the command on mongodb 4.0.1 with python 3.6, it works fine, you just one extra closing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks or the comments.
There is no exception. I just doesn't work.
The extra closing parethesis above is a copy/paste error that doesn't exist in the actual code.

Comment: @Ryan which version of PyMongo are you using ? by does not work, do you mean the field `user_id` is still set ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar version 3.7.1 -- Yes, that's what I mean.  It doesn't throw an error. I just doesn't work.

Comment: You may be using a newer version of pymongo. Try update_one instead of update